# Single image for horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with a title and various horizontal links below. I would the background image to extend to all of it. What I mean by that is that I would like to have just one image instead of repeated tile like images. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Here is a [fiddle of my failed attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3pY/).

I also tried to add a `div` around the entire `<title>` + `<ul>` of menu items and then just adding the image to the `div`. that didn't work either.

Comment: try background:url(img.jpg);
background-size:80px 60px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

Comment: for a div wrapped around the entire thing?

Comment: yes for the div, or u can try it for ul. the sizes i mentioned are for example, edit to your need. also make sure you have set height and width and float for the div or ul. also mention overflow as auto or hidden for it. just to make sure the parent covers the child area

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3pY/2/  - didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **css** of `.navMenu ul`

```
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3pY/4/)

And since you have `float`ed the `div`s, dont forget to add `.clr{clear:both}` class in the end(*i have added it,in the end, notice that*)

**EDIT**

[**Final DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3pY/8/)

Your title is outside the `navmenu`, so to wrap it under the same `bg`, you'll have to put everything inisde same class.....have done it through `<div id="bg">` at the top.

and finally for submenu hover :

```
.navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    min-height:120px; /* this is important */
    height:100%;  /* this is important */
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image:url('http://www.youthedesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/14-wrinkled-paper-6.jpg');
}
```

this does the job pretty much....

Comment: not exactly. Notice the title doesnt have a background nor do the links.

Comment: @user2690363 : added an edit...check if that works for you! :)

Comment: I managed to get the same thing as you. You see the paper images on the individual links are actually different "instances" for lack of a better term of the image. I want just one image for the entire thing. You can't really tell with that image, but that isn't the one I am actually using. I am just using that one as a test. Does that make sense? Maybe there's some way  I can place the image on the background and only have it show in those areas? I am not sure. It is quite a hard one to crack, if it's even possible.

Comment: m not getting what you are saying....can you show some picture design about what you want to achieve!!???

Comment: I woul love to. However, I haven't seen any such thing unfortunately. Let's imagine this. A menu which has an entirely blue background. The `title` background is blue, the `ul, li, and a` are all on a blue background. Now, yes those are all *different* backgrounds, they appear as though they have one solid background because it's the same color. Imagine that it is a solid background and replace that with some image. It would almost be as if the image was "behind" the entire page and the only place it showed through was where the title is along with the `ul` and its dropdowns. Make sense?